# NewForm submit attachments javascript

Tags: javascript, newform, nintex

I am working on a Nintex new form which has an attachment control. If a user wants to attach multiple documents the user has to click on "Add Attachment" several times and add one file at a time. I have a requirements so the users are able to use Shift/Ctrl to select multiple files.

I have been able to utilize html "multiple" attribute on the `<input type="file" multiple>` control to allow users to upload multiple files. However, upon submitting the form, only the first attachment gets attached to the new item.

I was wondering if there is any documentation (I doubt this) or anyone knows where exactly in SharePoint js code is that that the attachments are being processed? I am thinking of intercepting that and extend it in a way that it iterates through the attached file rather than picking up only the first file.

Comment: already answered here for you. Not nintex related but custom related https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157717/sharepoint-2013-add-multiple-attachment-to-a-list-at-one-shot

Comment: Yes I came across that. That's for an existing SharePoint item though. Not on new form.